# Need clarity on groups, users and permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

OK, so I am trying to figure out how to add a user to the "www-data" group. I also want to change the "sudo" group's permissions too (not user permissions, but permissions for the entire group!).

Can anybody help me with this before I follow a guide on the 'net and make a permissions error elsewhere on the system? (!)

What exactly does the output of `id pi` mean, i.e. "uid=/gid=/groups="?

`uid=1000(pi) gid=1000(pi) groups=1000(pi),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),
44(video),46(plugdev),60(games),100(users),105(netdev),999(input),1001(indiecity),1002(spiuser)`

And what are secondary groups and how do you add them? I was under the impression that I had a group called `www-data` yet when I do just `groups` I get the following output that doesn't even list it:

```
pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users netdev input indiecity spiuser
```

Lastly, how do I change the permissions of a group (not a user within the group)?

Comment: You don't want to follow "a guide  on the 'net", but ask for one? We cannot do the very basic reading on that topic for you; fetch a book or whatever document you prefer on unix and read through it. Also, you're much to unspecific on what you want to do; and you're asking half a dozen questions in one question which probably better should have been split up as several independent ones.

Comment: @JensErat: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

- `groups` prints all groups your current user is in.
- To add an user to a group in Debian based systems, use `adduser username groupname`, eg. `adduser pi www-data`.
- For the output of `id`, read `man id` - in a very brief form it prints your user id and name, primary group id and name, and all other groups with id and name.
- You can be in multiple groups, while one is your first group, all others are secondary.
- You cannot assign permissions to a group, but you can set a file's group using `chgrp` and give the group permissions using `chmod`. For more details have a look at the man pages.
- For information on how to configure the `sudo` group, have a look at `/etc/sudoers` and read the sudoers manual page.

It seems you want to administrate a web server. *Right now you're lacking most basic unix knowledge*, start learning about unix and linux in general before administrating production servers.